# Accessing Newer Version of Variable from Different Scope (JavaScript / jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scope

I want to populate the results div with the already loaded variable, data1, when the back button is clicked.  With this code, when the back button is clicked, the results div gets set to "".  How do I access the newer version of data1?

Javascript:

```
function finddata(def,id){
    $("#doctitle").html($("#exp").val() + " - Writer's Dictionary");
    $("#results").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog glyphicon-spin" title="loading..."></span>').fadeIn();
    if (def == 1) {
        var word = id.innerHTML;
        $.get( "processor.php?query=" + word + "&def=" + def, function(data2) {
            $("#results").html(data2);
            $("#back").click(function(){
                $("#results").html(data1);
            });
        });
    } else {
        $.get( "processor.php?query=" + $("#exp").val(), function(data1) {
            $("#results").html(data1);
        });
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="results">
    <div id="back">Back</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<div id="back" onclick="finddata(2)">Back</div>
```

to set `def` parameter to value other than `1` , which should call `$.get()` within `else` statement of `finddata`

---

Edit, Updated

```
var data;

function finddata(def) {
  if (def === 1) {
    // do stuff
  } else {
    // if `data` defined
    if (data) {
     // do not do stuff here
    } 
    // else call `.get()`
    else {
      var word = id.innerHTML;
      $.get( "processor.php?query=" + word + "&def=" + def, function(data2) {
        $("#results").html(data2);
        $("#back").click(function(){
            $("#results").html(data1);
        });
      });
    }
  }
}
$("#back").click(function() {
  finddata(2)
})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/229ad2b2/2/

Comment: Yes, that would work, but is there a way to load data1 so the user doesn't have to load from internet again?

Comment: _"Yes, that would work, but is there a way to load data1 so the user doesn't have to load it again?"_ Not certain interpret comment correctly ? Why would user "have to load it again" ?

Comment: Because if you evoked finddata() again, you would be loading data1 from the internet instead of from the already downloaded variable data1.

Comment: @John Try using `.one()` to call handler for click event at most once. `$("#back").one("click", function() {finddata(2)})` ; alternatively , could declare `data1` outside of `finddata` `var data1;function findata(){}` ; then at  `else {if(data1) {$("#result").html(data1)} else {$.get().then(function(data1) {data1 = data1})}}`

Comment: @John If `data1` is defined , do not call `$.get()` a second time ; instead populate `#results` `html` with `data1` , which would have been set from previous call to `$.get()` from `undefined` to `data1` jquery promise return value at `.then()`

Comment: @John Does `data1` populate `#results` with new `#back` element ?

Comment: @John See http://jsfiddle.net/229ad2b2/ ; substituted `.append()` for `.html()` to not overwrite `#back` within `#results`

Comment: @John Tried jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/229ad2b2/ ? Note, changed variable name to `var data` outside scope of `finddata` , `.then()`

Comment: Isn't it just possible to have an if statement `if (data1) { $("#results").html(data1);}

Comment: @John Yes. Though would initialize variable name to one different than `data1` jsquery promise argument returned at `.then()` . This is approach attempted at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/229ad2b2/

Comment: What is the advantage of using a post request?

Comment: @John _"What is the advantage of using a post request?"_ No advantage. `$.post()` is used for demonstration purposes , how jsfiddle returns value ; see http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html

Comment: this still loads the new data from the web when you click back instead of displaying the info that was just there.

Comment: @John _"this still loads the new data from the web when you click back instead of displaying the info that was just there."_ Commented  `$("#results").append(data)` ; `click` handler should do nothing if `data` is defined and `#back` clicked , though logged `data` to `console` , which can also be commented or removed  at http://jsfiddle.net/229ad2b2/2/